# Run CMD Minimized/Hidden

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I use the following code to execute a command line executable.  It does work, but it opens to a CMD window that is full size and blocks the form that I use to call it.  Over our VPN, this may take a considerable amount of time and I would like to have it minimized or hidden to prevent the user from possible aborting the CMD window.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Process.Start(My.Settings.BatchExeLoc, ProcessParameters.ToString).WaitForExit()
```

Comment: We really need a little more information about your executable file. Is your executable file a packaged batch file which is extracted and run? What is the executable file supposed to do? Why is it using a `cmd.exe` window? What have you tried yourself in fixing the issue? In order to assist you we need to be able to replicate your issue, and to do that we need more information.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP self resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Ran across this in another forum.  Sorry to waste any ones time.

```
Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
```