# Start CMD Window Minimized?

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I use the following code to start a process and then wait for it to exit.  It works, but the CMD window is full size.   I'd rather have it start at least minimized or possibly hidden. Thanks in advance!

Edit: If I am doing this in a method does not allow me to change the method in which to specify either hidden or minimized, how do I go about this?

```
mProcessParameters = New StringBuilder
mProcessParameters.Append(" -input:" & Chr(34) & "\\server\waybill\Waybill files\")
mProcessParameters.Append(txt_Year.Text & " Data\Interim Data Processing\")
mProcessParameters.Append(mBPGM_FileNames(mLooper2) & mInFileNameSuffix & Chr(34) & " ")
mProcessParameters.Append(" -config:" & Chr(34) & "\\server\waybill\Waybill files\")
mProcessParameters.Append(txt_Year.Text & " Data\Interim Data Processing\")
mProcessParameters.Append(mBPGM_FileTypes(mLooper2) & mCfgFileNameSuffix & Chr(34))
mProcess.Start(My.Settings.BatchProg, mProcessParameters.ToString).WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Like probably: https://www.dotnetperls.com/process-vbnet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run CMD Minimized/Hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524762/run-cmd-minimized-hidden)

Comment: You have not provided anything in that code which indicates that you're running the 'CMD window', `cmd.exe`. That suggests that you're running an executable which itself invokes the `cmd.exe`, and in doing that, removes your control over it. Please expand your question via the [edit] facility, so that we have sufficient information to reproduce your specific issue.

Comment: I understand that I apparently doing this using a method that does not allow me to control/specify the cmd.exe window visibility.  How do I go about doing this?  The program that is being called just needs to be called, the window to be minimized or hidden, that the calling vb.net program wait until the called program finishes, and the window closes when the called program finishes.

Comment: If your process is a CLI one, then you would probably need to start the `cmd.exe` process, hidden or minimized, with the `/C` or `/K` option, and run your process as one or more arguments appended to it.

Comment: Well, since you've got what I'm guessing is a WinForms app, why does it need to run the BatchProg?  Can't that functionality be integrated directly into your app?  Is it doing anything special that requires it being an external app?

Comment: It is a proprietary program from a third party that can only be run from a command line.